# Problem after upgrade application to CodeIgniter 3

Tags: php, codeigniter-3

I just upgraded my CodeIgniter from version 2.2 to 3.1.10. I replace system folder and its contents and rename all controller name to capitalized and everything else needed. Then I got this error:

```
A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Warning
Message: Declaration of MY_Router::set_directory($dir) should be compatible with CI_Router::set_directory($dir, $append = false)
Filename: core/MY_Router.php
Line Number: 0
```

Inside `application/core` there are some files:

- MY_Route.php
- MY_Input.php
- MY_Controller.php
- etc

UPDATED: here is a piece of code in `MY_Route`

```
function set_directory($dir)
{
    // Allow forward slash, but don't allow periods.
    $this->directory = str_replace('.', '', $dir) . '/';
}
```

I'm sure that the problem is caused by these files but I have no idea what to do. I read the documentation how to upgrade but no clue about this problem. Anyone can help me please?

Comment: post the code from `core/MY_Router.php`, the `set_directory` method

Comment: @BinarWeb, I just updated my question with the code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe help you. You need add argument:

```
function set_directory($dir, $append = false) <-- edit
{
    // Allow forward slash, but don't allow periods.
    $this->directory = str_replace('.', '', $dir) . '/';
}
```